# How to avoid keyerror with two forms with two submit buttons in HTML

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have 2 separate forms on my page, and I gave them 2 separate submit buttons (has to be like that because of the task), they would initiate a search each. The problem is that when I check on values in an if/elif statement if one of the forms is empty, I get an error message for it and I don't understand why, since I originally tried it like this: `if request.form["applicant_name"]: do something` which is supposed to check if it exists right?

Anyway here is the code in my html and my server.py file below:

```
  <h3>Search for applicants</h3>
  <form action="/applicant-phone" method="post" id="form1">
    <input
      type="text"
      name="applicant-name"
      id="form1"
      placeholder="Applicant name"
    />
    <button type="submit" form="form1">Search</button>
  </form>

  <form action="/applicant-phone" method="post" id="form2">
    <input
      type="text"
      name="email-ending"
      id="form2"
      placeholder="Email ending"
    />
    <button type="submit" form="form2">Search</button>
  </form>
</section>
```

```
    name = request.form["applicant-name"]
    email = request.form["email-ending"]


    if name:
        applicant_details = data_manager.get_applicant_data_by_name(name)
        return render_template('applicants.html', applicants=applicant_details)
    elif email:
        applicant_details = data_manager.get_applicant_data_by_email_ending(email)
        return render_template('applicants.html', applicants=applicant_details)

    return redirect("/")
```

Sadly it runs on an error on the first lines when I try to get the variables in the functions, it ran on an error when I tried to check on the `request.form` data in the If statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, with regular Python dicts, indexing with `[...]` raises a KeyError if `...` is not in the dictionary. Change the indexing to `.get()`; it returns a default value if the key is not found; the default default is `None`.

```
name = request.form.get("applicant-name")
email = request.form.get("email-ending")
```

You can also simplify your code to not have multiple `render_template` calls:

```
name = request.form.get("applicant-name")
email = request.form.get("email-ending")

applicant_details = None

if name:
    applicant_details = data_manager.get_applicant_data_by_name(name)
elif email:
    applicant_details = data_manager.get_applicant_data_by_email_ending(email)

if applicant_details is not None:
    return render_template("applicants.html", applicants=applicant_details)

return redirect("/")
```